# I want to type \text{coker} in normal font but not italic font in thm enviroment like \ker

Tags: fonts

I have a question about `\text{}`.

For convenience, I define many new commands, for example `\def\im{\text{Im}}`, `\def\coker{\text{coker}}`, etc.. I expect my new commands work like `\ker`, and really work that way in usual situation. But, in italic font enviroments(`thm`, `prop`, etc..), `\im` and `\coker` typed in italic font. I want they type in normal font like `\ker`.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Since `ker` is an operator, `\coker` should be defined using `\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}`, in my point of view. This will use upright letters

Comment: Never **ever** use `\text` for this, try using it in an italic context, and you'll see why it is so wrong. Use the solutions either linked to or provided by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your preamble (I suppose you already load  `amsmath` or `mathtools`):

```
     \DeclareMathOperator\coker{coker}
```

or

```
     \DeclareMathOperator\coker{Coker}
```

if you write in French (and possibly some other languages).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `amsmath`'s

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
```

in the first place, which handles this for you.